# wordpress "Pages" permalinks not working, all redirect to homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

My wordpress site is acting weird. The problem is like this:

The page `www.mysite.com/about-us` is not showing, but showing the homepage content.

Also when you type some not exiting pages like `www.mysite.com/abcdef` also show the homepage, not a `404 error`.

(I am using the link structure `/%category%/%postname%.html`. and a plugin called `no parent categories` which removes the parent categories from the link.)

I tried to set the link structure to default and disable the plugin, still no use.

can anybody kindly help?

Comment: Only suggestion I've got is to delete the .htaccess file and go to the permalinks page and re-save your settings. If you don't have a 404 file in the theme directory, it will default to index.php, this might explain why you're seeing your homepage on URLs that don't exist.

Comment: i tried what you said, still no luck. i have a 404 file, and it works fine on non-exiting posts like"www.mysite.com/category/this-post-doesnt-exit.html". but thanks for your help!

Comment: i finally figured it out. People who facing the same problem, try reinstall wordpress and Do not use "no parent categroy" plugin any more.  I think it will mess up the link structure /%category%/%postname%.html. so just leave it. Now my site is working fine.